# Auto-renewable subscriptions and change of Apple ID

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, in-app-purchase, subscriptions

What should the appropriate action be when a user is in a valid auto-renewable subscription period and the Apple ID on the device is changed? I.e. user signs out in the settings app

I can't seem to find any documentation on this and it doesn't look like there are any sort of notifications that get triggered for this event. Should the app just continue to make the content available to user for the rest of the period?